# Can we change a[i] pointed by character pointer *a?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
char *a="abc";
a[0]='A';
```

or

```
*a='A';
```

gives me segmentation fault. Is it possible to change it? Also explain why is it giving me segmentation fault. (GCC is being used)

Comment: See [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)